# Base64 Image storage

Tags: javascript, base64, store

I have  some input (type-file) on a page and the image are are implemented into divs. I want to use base 64 to store the images (localstorage) the user puts into them.

I've had a look here on stackoverflow for an answer but can't seem to find out how it works.

I understand this may not be the best way to store the users images, so if someone has an equally simple alternative, that would be much appreciated.

Comment: I'ts not quite clear what you're trying to achieve for me..

Comment: Im trying to save images into localstorage and load them back in. I've heard you can do it using base64. I'm just not sure how

Answer (score 1):

the base64 is the interpretation of the image in 64 bit. It return a long string you can store in any place (cookies, localstorage etc...).
But this string is really big and i suggest you not storing too many images.

After getting your encoding string, you just have to display the image with:

```
<img  src="data:image/png;base64,Your64StringImage..." />
```

Here a website to convert an image in 64 bit string :http://webcodertools.com/imagetobase64converter

Comment: But what about if I dont know what the image would be. The user will be using the images from their device and so I will not know which images will have to be converted into a 64 bit string